# Programmatically Editing a TFS Work Item Field from an OS X Application

Tags: java, tfs

Doing some research for a student project we're working on (only looking for advice here!) and I was hoping I might field some questions about interacting with TFS from an OS X machine. Our end goal is to develop a simple application that is able to update/display the amount of time spent//allocated on that work item. The available .NET libraries would make quick work of this problem if we were developing for Windows but we're encountering problems developing this for OS X.

From searching Google and SO I've found several claims that working with TFS on OS X is impossible beyond very basic version control operations and I was hoping to get confirmation that as of March 2015 that is still the case. Many of the questions I've seen are from '10-'13 and I haven't been able to find any information that suggests progress since. My question is: **Is it even possible to programmatically connect to a TFS server from an OS X machine, retrieve field data for a work item, and update field data for a work item?**. It is my opinion that my team is beginning to spend time pursuing a C# solution that will ultimately not ever work.

Here is what we have tried so far and why it didn't work:

- Develop application using Xamarin Mac//Mono .NET - The TFS API
  available on NuGet makes Win32 specific calls (advapi32.dll) and thus
  far we have had no luck using downloaded .dll's. When we use the TFS API on NuGet we get lots of warnings about missing DLLs.
- Interact with TFS using web services - In so far as I can tell the only way to interact with TFS is using SOAP and the exposed services don't appear to accomplish what we'd need. [List of TFS services](http://sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/TFS_2010_Web_Services)

Here is what we are going to try and why we think it might work:

- Utilize the Java SDK - The provided java libraries may play more nicely
  cross-platform than the C# libraries.
- Force our team to switch to Visual Studio Online - Supports a REST
  api, can interface with TFS. Costs money after 5 users.

Is there a solution that will allow us to create a stand alone application that is able to connect to TFS, query the server for work item fields, and allow updates to work item fields that runs on OS X? Any feedback would be appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to read this question.

Comment: You may consider that the vNext (aka TFS2015) will support REST API also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a full java API as part of the team explorer everywhere. You can use that on any platform that runs java.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40785

Comment: So far, the java sdk seems to meet our needs! It was a bit strange to configure at first but seems to be going smoothly. Would up vote if I could